# I've just purchased a VPS: What are the first things I should do to keep it secure

Tags: linux, vps

So I've just purchased a VPS to mess around with and host some of my sites.

I've changed the password to a 15 digit alphanumeric string via SSH, but I would like to know what basic security measures I should take to begin with.

For example, should I continue to use root to login - I've a faint memory of being told this is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

> I've changed the password to a 15 digit alphanumeric string via SSH

You could even disable passwords and use [key-based authentication](https://www.google.de/search?q=key+based+authentication+linux) only by setting the option `PermitRootLogin without-password` in `/etc/sshd/ssh_config`. Assuming that the key generator works properly (there was an [incident on Debian systems in the past where it didn't](http://it.slashdot.org/story/08/05/13/1533212/debian-bug-leaves-private-sslssh-keys-guessable)), an SSH key is much safer than a password.

> but I would like to know what basic security measures I should take to begin with.

I think the most important thing you have to do is keep the machine always up-to-date, by setting up some kind of autoupdate (for example `cron-apt` in Debian).

> For example, should I continue to use root to login - I've a faint memory of being told this is a bad thing.

This is a common security advice, but in my personal opinion it doesn't have any merit. Using the root account combined with `PermitRootLogin without-password` is IMO much safer than using a password-protected account with `sudo`. If an attacker gains access to your unprivileged account, he could alias `sudo` to send him your password, or he could use a possible root exploit to gain root permissions. I'd consider a machine to be compromised as soon as an attacker has gained access to account, be it privileged or not.

Disabling the root account also makes certain things unnecessarily complicated, for example using `scp` or `rsync` to access files that are only read/writable for root.

Comment: Logging in as a non-root user does have the advantage of reducing the damage faulty/malicious software can do. It can also make it a bit more difficult to get into SSH, because both the username and password may be unknown.

Answer (score 1):

First, think about it from a machine point of view.

What ports are open on your machine and where's my firewall ?

Basically LOCK IT DOWN.

Restrict (firewall, preferable) only connections to one port from internet for admin - don't use 22; use a different number.

- Best to use an obscure number.
- Test it.
- When it works remove standard port (22).
- restart sshd
- login again (new port!)

If everything else blocked, you can now relax.

Now I would create a non-privileged user that can login via ssh and public/private key; make sure this user can become root by logging on as user A. 
- Now you can disable root login via ssh seed `man sshd_config` `/etc/sshd.config`

Now you can start to administer ..

- install or start new services
- test via ssh redirects first
- and then, open ports gradually as tested. (80, 443, ... on firewall to server ports)